# In swing-java, where does the Graphics instance come from?

Tags: java, swing, repaint

When an update request is delivered to swing (either system triggered e.g. because of a resize or a block by another window, or app-triggered e.g. by a call to repaint() method), how is this request actually handled? What procedure takes place in that RepaintManager thing?

Comment: How detailed do you need it to be? If _very_ detailed, you might look at the source code, otherwise a good place to start would be the official documentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Comment: Thank you, I read both. but didn't understand how is the *Graphics* instance generated. I traced the pre to some *peer.getGraphics()* (called inside *Component.getGraphics()*) where I assumed *peer* is the heavyweight peer (which was mentioned in your link). but there I lost the track. do you know what happens in *peer.getGraphics()*?

Answer (score 3):

From your comment:

> Do you know what happens in peer.getGraphics()?

That depends on which peer implementation is used.

One implementation is `WComponentPeer` (used when running on Windows), which seems to use two ways for getting the `Graphics` object:

1. If the component has a parent of type `Window` (or is one itself) which in turn has a back buffer immage associated, that image's `Graphics` object is returned. This depends on the type of image but is most likeley a `SunGraphics2D` instance, created in `createGraphics()`.
2. Otherwise a `ScreenUpdateManager` instance is retrieved and `createGraphics(...)` is called on it which in turn returns a new `SunGraphics2D` instance.

Please note that this is just one possible way and it highly depends on the OS, the JVM and UI toolkit used.